# Why do I get 0 neighbors in my KNN model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn, multiclass-classification

I'm doing a multi-class audio classification, where I have

1) paths to each .wav file which records an individual word 
2) a vector of MFCCs for each path 
3) a label (the actual word) for each path in the training set

Apparently, my algorithm is not recognizing any neighbor. Any reason?

My sets look like:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(new_X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=5)
print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(y_test.shape)
```

(56894, 99)
(56894,)
(37930, 99)
(37930,)

My model is:

```
k_range = list(range(1))
scores = []
for k in k_range:
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
    knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)
    scores.append(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

then the error says:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-d67236a4ac61> in <module>()
      3 for k in k_range:
      4     knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
----> 5     knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
      6     y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)
      7     scores.append(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/base.py in fit(self, X, y)
    915             self._y = self._y.ravel()
    916 
--> 917         return self._fit(X)
    918 
    919 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/base.py in _fit(self, X)
    266                 raise ValueError(
    267                     "Expected n_neighbors > 0. Got %d" %
--> 268                     self.n_neighbors
    269                 )
    270             else:

ValueError: Expected n_neighbors > 0. Got 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not failing to recognise neighbours, it's complaining that you're using `n_neighbours = 0`

Your loop uses `k_range` which is `[0,1]` so on the first iteration of the loop, the failing call evaluates to:

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=0)
```

You need to change the range in:

```
k_range = list(range(1))
```

to not include zero.

Comment: Thanks David! Actually, before it said ```k_range = list(range(1,26))``` but since it took forever I thought I could use 1 only. Now I'm using 1,3 but it still takes forever. Dyt of the reason?

Comment: You've got 5,632,506 (56894 * 99) data points in your training set so that's a lot of calculations in every iteration of KNN. You could consider working with a smaller randomised subset of the data to at least narrow down the range of `k` and then cross-validate.

Comment: Ok cool. Also, I have 35 labels, and someone now told me that then I should have 35 Ks. Does it have to do? I just thought of the 25 Ks as a regular standard... hadn't heard it was related to the amount of labels.